# WPF UserControl - click animation

Tags: xaml, animation

I have created a WFP `UserControl` with some complex XAML (converted from SVG).  It's basically a fancy button.

I would like to create an animation in the usercontrol's XAML to "shift" it's location by 4 pixels to the right and down, to simulate a click, and then have it pop back to its original location.

To me, this sounds like the first animation anyone would ever learn in WPF, but I'm having trouble finding a good example.

I have included the `UserControl` if anyone is interested.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PositionButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="50" Height="50">

<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="svg2" Width="48.618" Height="44.289">
    <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1">
         <Path Fill="#FFFFCC00" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1.25" StrokeMiterLimit="4" x:Name="path3240" Canvas.Left="-47.7386" Canvas.Top="-164.9827" Data="M90.521734,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,53.363626,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,90.521734,187.00391z">
        </Path>
        <Path x:Name="path4635" RenderTransform="0.8722467,0,0,0.8722467,0,0" Canvas.Left="-38.5477" Canvas.Top="-141.0923" Data="M90.521734,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,53.363626,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,90.521734,187.00391z">
            <Path.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="61.433315,163.5455" EndPoint="83.765717,207.83496" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad" Transform="Identity">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF9F9F9" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00F9F9F9" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="#FF000000" x:Name="text4651">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="18.202721,31.924561" IsClosed="True">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PolyLineSegment Points="13.89608,31.924561 18.779503,17.55542 17.125206,17.55542 18.095909,14.697998" />
                                <PolyBezierSegment Points="18.724808,14.698015 19.347163,14.429135 19.962975,13.891357 20.57877,13.353616 20.97326,12.829528 21.146446,12.319092" />
                                <PolyLineSegment Points="24.865196,12.319092 18.202721,31.924561" />
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="19.132408,31.924561" IsClosed="True">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PolyLineSegment Points="25.794884,12.319092 30.867149,12.319092" />
                                <PolyBezierSegment Points="32.079376,12.319111 33.0384,12.594827 33.744225,13.14624 34.450019,13.697691 34.596992,14.579526 34.185143,15.791748" />
                                <LineSegment Point="33.260582,18.512451" />
                                <PolyBezierSegment Points="32.792876,19.888765 31.624501,20.859467 29.755455,21.424561 31.37499,21.862071 31.938384,22.805429 31.445641,24.254639" />
                                <LineSegment Point="30.154503,28.05542" />
                                <PolyBezierSegment Points="29.714713,29.349693 28.964043,30.318117 27.902489,30.960693 26.840916,31.603272 25.726802,31.924561 24.560143,31.924561" />
                                <LineSegment Point="19.132408,31.924561" />
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="28.963341,19.209717" IsClosed="True">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <LineSegment Point="30.097252,15.873779" />
                                <BezierSegment Point1="30.329092,15.190202" Point2="30.043977,14.848406" Point3="29.241905,14.848389" />
                                <LineSegment Point="27.40731,20.248779" />
                                <BezierSegment Point1="28.209384,20.248791" Point2="28.728061,19.902437" Point3="28.963341,19.209717" />
                                <LineSegment Point="28.963341,19.209717" />
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="25.850426,28.369873" IsClosed="True">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <LineSegment Point="27.537193,23.406982" />
                                <BezierSegment Point1="27.769036,22.723398" Point2="27.483921,22.381601" Point3="26.681847,22.381592" />
                                <LineSegment Point="24.294395,29.408936" />
                                <BezierSegment Point1="25.096472,29.408938" Point2="25.615149,29.062584" Point3="25.850426,28.369873" />
                                <LineSegment Point="25.850426,28.369873" />
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel is right on all counts. I have made some XAML that demonstrates his approach:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="svgButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Canvas x:Name="svg2" Width="48.618" Height="44.289">
   <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1">
    <Path Fill="#FFFFCC00" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1.25" StrokeMiterLimit="4" x:Name="path3240" Canvas.Left="-47.7386" Canvas.Top="-164.9827" Data="M90.521734,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,53.363626,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,90.521734,187.00391z">
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path4635" RenderTransform="0.8722467,0,0,0.8722467,0,0" Canvas.Left="-38.5477" Canvas.Top="-141.0923" Data="M90.521734,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,53.363626,187.00391A18.579054,18.415361,0,1,1,90.521734,187.00391z">
     <Path.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="61.433315,163.5455" EndPoint="83.765717,207.83496" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad" Transform="Identity">
       <GradientStop Color="#FFF9F9F9" Offset="0" />
       <GradientStop Color="#00F9F9F9" Offset="1" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
    <Path Fill="#FF000000" x:Name="text4651">
     <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
       <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="18.202721,31.924561" IsClosed="True">
         <PathFigure.Segments>
          <PolyLineSegment Points="13.89608,31.924561 18.779503,17.55542 17.125206,17.55542 18.095909,14.697998" />
          <PolyBezierSegment Points="18.724808,14.698015 19.347163,14.429135 19.962975,13.891357 20.57877,13.353616 20.97326,12.829528 21.146446,12.319092" />
          <PolyLineSegment Points="24.865196,12.319092 18.202721,31.924561" />
         </PathFigure.Segments>
        </PathFigure>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="19.132408,31.924561" IsClosed="True">
         <PathFigure.Segments>
          <PolyLineSegment Points="25.794884,12.319092 30.867149,12.319092" />
          <PolyBezierSegment Points="32.079376,12.319111 33.0384,12.594827 33.744225,13.14624 34.450019,13.697691 34.596992,14.579526 34.185143,15.791748" />
          <LineSegment Point="33.260582,18.512451" />
          <PolyBezierSegment Points="32.792876,19.888765 31.624501,20.859467 29.755455,21.424561 31.37499,21.862071 31.938384,22.805429 31.445641,24.254639" />
          <LineSegment Point="30.154503,28.05542" />
          <PolyBezierSegment Points="29.714713,29.349693 28.964043,30.318117 27.902489,30.960693 26.840916,31.603272 25.726802,31.924561 24.560143,31.924561" />
          <LineSegment Point="19.132408,31.924561" />
         </PathFigure.Segments>
        </PathFigure>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="28.963341,19.209717" IsClosed="True">
         <PathFigure.Segments>
          <LineSegment Point="30.097252,15.873779" />
          <BezierSegment Point1="30.329092,15.190202" Point2="30.043977,14.848406" Point3="29.241905,14.848389" />
          <LineSegment Point="27.40731,20.248779" />
          <BezierSegment Point1="28.209384,20.248791" Point2="28.728061,19.902437" Point3="28.963341,19.209717" />
          <LineSegment Point="28.963341,19.209717" />
         </PathFigure.Segments>
        </PathFigure>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="25.850426,28.369873" IsClosed="True">
         <PathFigure.Segments>
          <LineSegment Point="27.537193,23.406982" />
           <BezierSegment Point1="27.769036,22.723398" Point2="27.483921,22.381601" Point3="26.681847,22.381592" />
           <LineSegment Point="24.294395,29.408936" />
           <BezierSegment Point1="25.096472,29.408938" Point2="25.615149,29.062584" Point3="25.850426,28.369873" />
           <LineSegment Point="25.850426,28.369873" />
          </PathFigure.Segments>
         </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry.Figures>
       </PathGeometry>
      </Path.Data>
     </Path>
    </Canvas>
   </Canvas>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
      <Setter.Value>
       <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
      </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
    </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>

 <Button Template="{StaticResource svgButton}"/>
```

Comment: All good, but you do not need a trigger for `False` case - the way triggers work, they change value to what it was originally when the trigger condition no longer applies, so just the `True` trigger should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

See `UIElement.RenderTransform`. For a button-like control, a typical way to do this is to make a property for your button, something like `IsPressed`, which your control sets to `true` in `OnMouseDown`, and then back to `false` in `OnMouseUp`. Then have a style with a trigger on `IsPressed == true`, which sets the `RenderTransform` to cause a shift - this is roughly how the normal WPF `Button` does this.

In your case, if your control has exact same behavior as the normal `Button`, only different look, I wouldn't actually use `UserControl` - I'd just create a custom style for the `Button`, with a custom template, and use that (and use `Button.IsPressed`).